# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

Tags: c#

my controller is showing errror pls solve showing error cannot convert an list to string

```
public JsonResult GetProperty_id(int selectedValue) 
{
    List < string > properties = new List < string > ().ToList();
    //    Property model1 = new Property();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=miracle\\SQLExpress; database=CRUIdb; user id=sa; password=dotnet");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT property_id  FROM Service_Property WHERE service_id =" + selectedValue, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++) 
    {
        properties = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["property_id"]); //error cannot covert
    }
    return Json(properties, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: @Jenish Rabadiya can you please have a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122189/onesignal-push-notification-clickevent-show-empty-values-windows-phone-8-1-c-sha

Comment: @Arsal It is not me who initiated this thread. I have just edited the question in order to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a `string` value to a `List<string>` which is not possible, instead you should add each value into your collection like below

```
properties.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["property_id"]);
```

Comment: Also, ToList is not required in first line. List < string > properties = new List < string > ().ToList();

Answer (score 2):

`ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["property_id"]` is a `string` but you are trying to set `properties` to that value. `properties` is `List<string>` from its declaration.

Perhaps you want to do `properties.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["property_id"])`, which would match the fact that after your loop you are accessing it when it would only take the value from the last loop even if it currently compiled.